# Passing a [ref] parameter in a remote session in Powershell

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, return, remoting

I have a Powershell question.

I am trying to get a value from a function to a variable, by calling a function with a reference to the variable.
For example:

```
$var = New.Object System.Object;
Example-Function -OutObject ([ref]$var);
```

Where the Example-Function is defined like this:

```
function Example-Function
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ref]
        $OutObject
    )
    $SomeValue = ...
    #Write some output
    #Do something...

    $OutObject.Value = $SomeValue;
}
```

This is working OK. The $var variable gets it's value from the function ($SomeValue).

But, this is not working when the Example-Function is imported into remote session, for example:

```
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('user','pass')
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName 'ExampleComputer' -Credential $creds -Authentication CredSSP

Import-PSSession -Session $session -CommandName 'Example-Function' -AllowClobber

$var = New.Object System.Object;
Example-Function -OutObject ([ref]$var);
```

This code is throwing the following error: **Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'OutObject'. Reference type is expected in argument.**

I am assuming that this is becuase the Example-Function is now running on the other computer ('ExampleComputer'), while ([ref]$var) is referencing the variable in memory of the computer running the scripts (my computer).
The reason I don't want to (cannot) use the return statement way is becuase my function is writing some output, and in Powershell, everything that is outputed from a function is returned.
So, my question is, can I get a value from a function that has a lot of output into the variable, when the function is running in the remote session?
If it cannot be done by using the [ref] parameter, is there another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay lets try again:

`Invoke-Command` returns whatever is run in the remote pipeline. Which means you can do:

```
$var = Invoke-Command -session $session -command {Example-Function}
```

Which saves everything in the `$var` variable. You can then filter the results and get whatever information you need.

And please remember `[ref]` just makes everything more complicated than it actually is.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but as I said, I am already using Write-Output for logging, and I won't get any output if I save everything into variable.
Also, are you sure that your second answer does any different then my example?

Comment: Okay you were right, I didn't answer your question. Please see the updated question

Comment: By this method I won't get any output on the screen, unless I output it after the function has finished processing. That means that I cannot get real-time output by using this methodd, and I need it.